# Kubernetes in GKE - Nginx Ingress deployment - Public IP assigned to Ingress resource

Tags: nginx, networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

TLDR, Why does the Ingress Resource have a public IP? Really, I'm seeking the why.

The description "Where 107.178.254.228 is the IP allocated by the Ingress controller to satisfy this Ingress." from the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress) doesn't really satisfy my need to understand it fully.

My understanding of the resource is that in this instance, it's acting as a pseudo-Nginx configuration, which does make sense to me based solely on the configuration elements. Though, the sticking point is why does itself, the resource, have a public IP? Following labs for this implementation, I also found that SSH is listening on this resource publicly, which I find strange. In testing, from the controller, the network path to this IP does egress the network so this isn't the case of another public IP being assigned on a VIF so that traffic can be routed on a local interface.

FWIW, my testing has been entirely in GKE but based on the documentation this seems to be simply "how it works" across platforms.

Comment: I am not sure on GKE but I beleive that if your service is of type Loadbalancer then it would create this IP, if not then this address would just be empty (My experience on AKS)

Comment: With Ingress you should have a nodeport service not a LoadBalancer one.

Answer (score 0):

Ingress used in GKE or cloud provider will have "the same effect" as a service Load Balancer in the way that it will create a load balancer resource on your cloud provider. That explains why it has a public IP.

If you don't need to have a Global load balancer (gce in annotation) you could limit yourself to a simple load balancer service.

Comment: When implementing the Nginx examples, A load balancer is provisioned with a public IP (which is self-explanatory). However, the ingress resource (not load balancer) also has a public IP. The explanation of why remains unclear, though I admit I might be missing something obvious. One point of note, if you deploy a second ingres resource the same IP is used as the first. Still unexplained to a degree, but worth noting.

Comment: That's strange, from what I tried each ingress is linked to the LB as it happens with a service LB and the external ip is the one of the generated lb. I should try again to be certain... You made a second deployment with for the second ingress?

Comment: Sorry, I created a second ingress-resource using Nginx and it created the resource with the same IP as the first. For reference and perhaps more reasonable comparison, I ran through the _NGINX Ingress Controller on Google Kubernetes Engine_ Qwiklab on google.qwiklabs.com and it exhibited this behavior as well. Which led to my puzzlement, to which I asked this same question of a Google trainer, and didn't get satisfaction, and here I am. :)